# C: Nested loop over 2d array giving unexpected result

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, cs50

This is a minimal reproducable example of the problem.
Having height and length as parameters (rather than calculate them) is deliberate.

```
typedef struct
{
    int red;
} triple;

int main(void)
{
    triple array[3][3] = {
      { {.red = 10}, {.red = 40}, {.red = 70}},
      { {.red = 110}, {.red = 120}, {.red = 130}},
      { {.red = 200}, {.red = 220}, {.red = 240}}
    };

printarray(2, 2, array);
}


void printarray(int height, int length, triple array[][length])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            printf("red score at array[%i][%i] = %i\n", i, j, array[i][j].red);
        }
    }
}
```

The output I get is:
red score at array[0][0] = 10
red score at array[0][1] = 40
red score at array[1][0] = 70
red score at array[1][1] = 110

But I would expect:
red score at array[0][0] = 10
red score at array[0][1] = 40
red score at array[1][0] = 110
red score at array[1][1] = 120

The indexing of the 2d array is clearly not working as I expect, but why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing `2,2` to `printarray`. This is `height,length`.

But, the array is *defined* with a length of `3`. So, you *must* pass `3` to `printarray` as the length.

Otherwise, the indexing in `printarray` is incorrect. As you have it, the array within `printarray` is equivalent to `triple array[2][2]` and *not* `triple array[3][3]` as is required.

The `height` can be less than the defined height, but `length` *must* match. Here, `length` is the *stride*. This is the number of elements in a given row.

So, in `main`, call with: `printarray(3,3,array)`

---

If you *truly* wish to print a subsection of the array, you'd need to pass a separate variable to `printarray` for the stride.

The function would have to be declared as:

```
void printarray(int height, int length, int stride, triple array[][stride])
```

Then, in `main`, call it with:

```
printarray(2,2,3,array);
```

Comment: yes ofcourse that was the problem, how could i not see it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your call to `printarray`:

```c
printarray(2, 2, array);
```

where you tell the function that the array has two rows and two columns - but it doesn't, it has three rows and three columns. The compiler assumes that you don't tell it lies!

You *must* call your function with the correct value of the `length` parameter, as this is used by the compiler to deduce how to calculate the offsets for an element `array[i][j]`.

If you only want to then print *part* of that array, you should specify the number of columns and rows to print as extra parameters to your function, like this:

```c
void printarray(int height, int length, int nrows, int ncols, triple array[][length])
{
    if (nrows > height) nrows = height;
    if (ncols > width) ncols = width;   // Prevent error conditions!
    for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ncols; j++) {
            printf("red score at array[%i][%i] = %i\n", i, j, array[i][j].red);
        }
    }
}
```

and then call the function like this:

```c
    printarray(3, 3, 2, 2, array);
```

Note: You are also missing a [function prototype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype) for `printarray` before its use, which will be an error on some compilers (but only a warning on others); add this line somewhere before your `main` function:

```c
void printarray(int height, int length, int nrows, int ncols, triple array[][length]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the guide, i realise my problem and fixed it